# Why is this FTP Download not outputting the downloaded data to my output file?

Tags: c#, ftp, stream, iostream, ftpwebrequest

I'm working on writing my own FTPDownload class and an encountering an issue after having changed some things around that I'm trying to address.

The code I'll paste below effectively starts a download and runs through it for some time, pulling full arrays of data in each iteration of the 'main' loop. What I can say for sure is that for small files ( for instance a meeting agenda in html ) get copied quickly and seemingly completely - however something is still quite off.

As we speak I'm downloading a 1.05 gig file, and my download status control is showing me 325 Megs complete - I can attest to the fact that this much data has been collected over the stream BUT, this is where things get weird... So far only 548 KB has been written to my output file.

The following method is doing the collecting, counting, and writing of the data - and before my recent changes it was performing rather well, with the exception of some performance issues I was intending to resolve by turn this into an extension of another series of classes.

```
class DownloadThread : StreamReader
{
    protected override void Cycle()
    {
        if (this.IsComplete)
        {
            this.FireEvent("OnComplete", new Event(this, "DownloadThread has confirmed completion of the targetted download."));
            this.Stop();
            return;
        }
        else if ((this._InputSource = this.GetResponseStream(this.RemotePath)) == null)
        {
            this.FireEvent("OnException",new Event(this,"DownloadThread could not execute. A Response Stream could not be retrieved from the Input Source '" + this.RemotePath + "'."));
            this.Stop();
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                this._StartTime = DateTime.Now;

                Byte[] Bytes = new Byte[4096];

                while ((this.BytesLastRead = this.Read(Bytes, 0, 4096)) > 0)
                {
                    this.LocalStream.Write(Bytes, 0, DataMetrics.Length(Bytes));
                    this.LocalStream.Flush();

                    this.BytesSinceLast += this.BytesLastRead;
                    this.TotalRead += this.BytesLastRead;

                    this.TriggerProgress();

                    continue;
                }
                return;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                this.FireEvent("OnException", new Event(this, "An exception was encountered while reading data for the download." + Environment.NewLine + e.Message + Environment.NewLine + e.StackTrace));
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    protected override Stream GetResponseStream(string RemotePath)
    {
        this.Request = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(this.RemotePath);

        if (this.Credentials != null)
            this.Request.Credentials = this.Credentials;

        this.Response = (FtpWebResponse)this.Request.GetResponse();

        Stream ResponseStream = this.Response.GetResponseStream();

        return ResponseStream;
    }
}
```

Something of note - before anyone jumps to conclusions - is that this 'cycle' method is automatically run inside of a loop in its own thread; and will recur every 'ThreadDelay' milliseconds ( assuming it returns ).

The 'LocalStream' variable in this class is as follows:

```
    protected Stream _LocalStream = null;

    protected Stream LocalStream
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.LocalFile == null)
                return null;
            else if (this._LocalStream == null)
            {
                if (!this.LocalDirectory.Exists)
                    this.LocalDirectory.Create();

                this._LocalStream = this.LocalFile.OpenWrite();

                return this.LocalStream;
            }
            else
                return this._LocalStream;
        }
    }
```

I've considered that this could cause some conflicts - and ensuring some thread safety is on my to-do list, but I'm not encountering any issues in this field at the moment - I just assumed someone might want to take a glance.

Per the 'DownloadThread.Read' method - since I'm sure someone will be curious... This is inherited from my own 'StreamReader' class; again inherited from my 'InputReader' class. Affiliated fields included below.

```
    protected Object _InputSource = null;

    public Object InputSource
    {
        get
        {
            return this._InputSource;
        }
    }

    public Stream InputStream
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.InputSource == null)
                return null;
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    return (Stream)this.InputSource;
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public override double Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        try
        {
            return this.InputStream.Read(buffer, offset, count);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            this.Stop();
            this.FireEvent("OnException", new Events.Event(this, "An exception was encountered while reading from the InputStream." + Environment.NewLine + e.Message + Environment.NewLine + e.StackTrace));
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Now - to reiterate - my issue here is that for some reason the data I am receiving is not being pushed out to the file properly. I'm just about to finish the ~1 gig download as I am finishing typing this, and thus far no exceptions have been thrown and the stream has not 'fallen apart' - but my output file is only 17 megs.

After waiting another 30 seconds to allow this download to finish, my 1.05 gig file has turned into an 18 meg file; but I see no particular reason why the above code shouldn't handle this properly.

Anyone's advice would be great.

Comment: 39 Views and not a single up-vote... Is my question not properly formed? Is there not enough data provided? I don't get it.

Comment: you can see one example from Microsoft with is much more readable and simple http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229711%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I appreciate the reference but this is where my initial code came from - the only real variance between this code and mine is that the above mentioned performs a 'ReadToEnd' while mine reads in chunks so I can better track how much has been downloaded. To reiterate - The download is running all the way to the end of the file, and IS pulling all of the data, but my local file is not being written the complete data that is being read.

Comment: what technology are you using?

Comment: You seem to always write to the beginning of the file, i.e. offset is 0 on your call to `Stream.Write`. Can you provide a **simplified** version of your code which illustrates the behavior you're trying to fix?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem might be in this line of code:

```
this.LocalStream.Write(Bytes, 0, DataMetrics.Length(Bytes));
```

I assume that your `DataMetrics.Length()` method returns the wrong number of bytes, thus I suggest you to try :

```
this.LocalStream.Write(Bytes, 0, this.BytesLastRead);
```

instead.

Comment: Hey @Yuriy; thanks for the attempt, but I've already tried swapping these variables to no avail. I can also say that ( at least for the first few dozen debugging passes ) the DataMetrics.Length method is returning an accurate number. It seems like I would almost get the same results if I just put a static '4096' into my Write ( Which I just might try to see what happens ).

Comment: @DigitalJedi805, after delving into `FileStream.Flush()` insides I revealed that it calls it's overload `Flush(flushToDisk: false)`, which boils down to the following code:
 `this.FlushInternalBuffer();  
 if(flushToDisk && this.CanWrite){ this.FlushOSBuffer(); }`
So from the looks of it you should either change your `LocalStream` property type to `FileStream` and call `Flush(true)` or simply enclose your `while` cycle in using statement `using(this.LocalStream){ while ... }` and let the CLR handle the disposing, closing and flushing of the stream.

Answer (score 0):

> Something of note - before anyone jumps to conclusions - is that this
>   'cycle' method is automatically run inside of a loop in its own
>   thread; and will recur every 'ThreadDelay' milliseconds ( assuming it
>   returns ).

My first guess is that the OS is discarding data on the network card since it isn't actively being dequeued, which is why you're getting 17mb instead of 1gb.